# How can I prevent BIDS from automatically checking out SSIS packages?

Tags: ssis, bids

I have Visual Studio 2005 (BIDS) set to "Check out automatically" when a file is edited which works well for most file types.

When I access a Data Flow within an SSIS package though, a check out is triggered without me making any changes. When I compare the files, there does not appear to have been any changes made in the background either.

This behaviour is annoying because I lose track of which files I actually made changes to and because I am potentially taking locks on files that I am not interested in editing.

I only found [one reference](http://www.developerdotstar.com/community/node/456) to this problem while researching it on the net but there was unfortunately no solution provided. I can confirm that the problem appears to be related to conditionals (as described in Daniel's post).

I changed from "Check out automatically" to "Prompt for checkout" but was then presented with a series of prompts which I needed to cancel before I could actually view the data flow.

Is there any way that I can prevent these files from being automatically checked out without having to face all of the prompts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scott, try Tools - Options - Source Control - Environment and select "Do nothing" option in Editing drop-down.

This option will allow you to view the data flow without prompts, but you'd have manually checkout files before you'd be able edit them. See if it works for you.

Comment: I was still prompted with a message that started as follows.

The connectors could not be refreshed for the following paths: 
 Path 'Yes' (ID: 69547): Unable to checkout the current file.  The file may be locked, or you may need to check the file out manually.

Comment: The warnings were annoying but this solution did help in some cases.

Comment: @ScottMunro To remove the error message you can check the "Allow checked-in files to be edited".