# Project wants to check out .dtproj in SSIS project every time TFS Get Latest is performed

Tags: tfs, ssis, bids

Using Team Foundation server and BIDS 2008, I receive a screen to check out the dtproj file every time the Get Latest operation is performed.

Steps to Produce:
I have no files checked out after performing a "Get Latest" from solution explorer.
I click to open the solution file .sln from Solution Explorer and the SSIS project opens.
I then receive a "Check Out" screen asking me to Check Out the .dtproj file.

Any ideas how to keep this from happening?

Comment: This happens for us all the time as well.  It has to do with multiple users using SSIS 2005/2008 solution under TFS, and seems to have to do with everyone having a slightly different database file name in each project.  One person checks in ... others get latest and it checks it out for them.  I don't know of any workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imperfect answer: [How can I prevent BIDS from automatically checking out SSIS packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862520/how-can-i-prevent-bids-from-automatically-checking-out-ssis-packages)

Also related: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/sqlintegrationservices/thread/654d556f-3826-4fd3-a36a-e7f20a059569

Comment: This is the best information I could find as well.  Thanks for everyone's input.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using BIDS 2008 with TFS 2010 for quite sometime but never had the issue that you are facing. Here are the Source Control settings on my BIDS environment.

Some of the other links that might help you:

[A project is automatic check outs everytime when i opens the solution in TFS 2008](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/1c2c37f6-4816-4f62-8088-639f34e95ab9/)

[How to stop Visual Studio from "always" checking out solution files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085978/how-to-stop-visual-studio-from-always-checking-out-solutions-files)

[image: Plug-in Selection]

[image: Environment]

[image: Visual Studio Team Foundation Server]

Answer (score 0):

This behavior appears to stop if you manually add the .database file to TFS through Source Control Explorer, making sure that the .database filename inside the .dtproj is the same name as the file you add to TFS.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the .database file is a local 'runtime' type file that Visual Studio creates each time. It is not an actual source file and should not be checked into source safe. What I think happens is that:

1. This file gets created by VS
2. At some point someone checks it into source safe, making the file read only in their working folder
3. Next time VS tries to create the file again. It can't (unless it's checked out) so it creates another one with a slightly different name
4. Because the filename is now different is changes the `.dtproj` file that references it. It therefore tries to check the `.dtproj` file out because a change has automatically been made to it
5. Chaos and confusion ensues

This is roughly what we did to fix this:

1. Delete any `.database` files from source control, ensure that it never gets added back again
2. Close VS
3. Backup and delete any `.database` files from local dev folder
4. Open VS and get latest
5. You might get 'this project couldn't be loaded' type errors in VS because the referenced `.database` file is missing
6. To get the project loaded, you need to get a valid `.database` file (these can get corrupted - check the file contents) into your local folder, and edit the `.dtproj` file in a text editor to point at the valid file
7. Once you have your .dtproj file working, check it in and have everyone get latest
8. Make sure no one ever checks in the .database file

Why oh why is it called a .database file when it has nothing to do with a database. When you search online for .database you get...... information about databases, not this annoying VS file.